# Modify current list by adding an element - Haskell 101

Tags: list, haskell, immutability

I'd like to add an element on the "movies" list of a data type `Director` variable called `billy`.

```
type Name  = String
type Movie = String
data Director = Director {name:: Name, movies::[Movie]}
    deriving (Show)
let billy = Director "Billy J." ["Good movie 1"]

--addMovieToDirector :: Movie -> Director -> Director
addMovieToDirector m (Director n ms) = Director n (m:ms)
```

The problem is previous function doesn't update billy's list of movies, it creates a new `Director` with the desired list (the changes are not stored on billy). How can I operate on billy's list without creating another `Director`? I understand, that Haskell works with constants, but then should I create a different 'billy' "variable" every time I modify the list?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. In Haskell you usually construct a new director each time, but Haskell offers some syntax to make this more convenient.

Comment: Modifying a list is just like modifying a 42, neither makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that just because it *looks* like you are creating a new `Director` value, that doesn't necessarily mean the compiler *will* create a new one. Experimental features like linear types help the compiler decide if it is safe to simply mutate the argument under the hood.

Comment: Note that in your code, the `let` expression isn't complete. Such `let` "statements" are only valid inside a `do` expression or in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you would like to do can be described as "in-place modification", or "using mutable data".

There are ways for Haskell to do this. Since in-place modification of anything almost always considered as a "side-effect", such things can only be done in the IO monad, or with dirty tricks like `unsafePerformIO`.

These are somewhat advanced topics, and at a beginner level it is arguably beneficial to think about Haskell values as being totally immutable.

So yes, you can't modify variables. Actually there are no "variables" at all.

Think about `billy` as a name for a value, not a variable.

All a function can do in Haskell is to take arguments, and calculate some result *without any side effects*.

This is probably the biggest mental barrier for people coming from imperative languages: "how should I work with data if I can't modify it"?

The answer is: you should structure your program like giant assembly line: raw materials (raw data, initial parameters, etc.) are put on the line at the beginning (the first function you call), and each workstation (function) does something useful (returns a value), consuming the result of the previous workstation. At the end, something valuable might fall off the line.

What I described is simple function composition: if you need to do `c` task after `b`, after `a`, on a value `x`, then you can write it as `(c . b . a) x`, or `c (b (a x))` or rather `c $ b $ a x`.

This way, you can write programs without ever *changing* anything explicitly, and only describing how to create new things out of old ones.

This sounds awfully inefficient, and indeed, there are some performance implications of functional programming (let alone laziness). However the compiler is smart enough to figure out a whole lot thing about programs written in Haskell, and optimize it in certain ways.

I hope it'll all make sense soon. :)

Oh, and welcome to Haskell. ;)

Comment: By the way, the term "variable" in Haskell is used as in mathematics. A variable `x` "varies" since if we define `f x = 2*x+4` we can later on call `f` on several different `x`s, making the argument "vary". This is not the same thing as mutation in imperative programming, though, where in the same call of `f` we can change the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [State](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) monad if you want to have a mutable state in your program, for some reason. Here's an example:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State

type GameValue = Int
type GameState = (Bool, Int)

type Name  = String
type Movie = String
data Director = Director {name:: Name, movies::[Movie]}
    deriving (Show)

addMovieToDirector :: Movie -> Director -> Director
addMovieToDirector m (Director n ms) = Director n (m:ms)


handleDirector :: Name -> State Director Director
handleDirector m = do
    director <- get
    put (addMovieToDirector m director)
    returnDirector

returnDirector = do
    director <- get
    return director

startState = Director "Billy J." ["Good movie 1"]

main = print $ evalState (handleDirector "Good movie 2") startState
```

The printed result will be

> Director {name = "Billy J.", movies = ["Good movie 2","Good movie 1"]}

Here `handleDirector` function of type `Name -> State Director Director` has a mutable state inside it of type `Director` and a "result" value of type, again, `Director`. `get` means get the state, `put` is used to change it and `evalstate` is used to "calculate" the result, enveloped by the constructed `State` monad.

Comment: What is the point of the `State` monad here? `addMovieToDirector` still creates a new `Director` each time it is called; you've just wrapped it in an unnecessary layer.

Comment: @chepner In my opinion, the matter of question is to have a mutable variable of type `Director`, not neccessary the mutable object itself. It's exactly, what `State` monad does. Of course, `Director` object itself is still (and always) immutable, but now one can work with a mutable value of those type inside `handleDirector`. In this minimal example I do the only state change - `put (addMovieToDirector m director)`. However, this logic can be more complicated. The purpose of all this work is out of scope.

Comment: "How can I operate on billy's list without creating another Director?" This answer doesn't accomplish that.